# How to write multi input in sql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dynamicquery

This is my code

I want to get table to use dynamic query

Single input works well

But multi input not works

This is my procedure

```
`drop procedure if exists listview;
delimiter //
create procedure listview( inq_type text, inq_mccd text, inq_prod text, inq_item text)
begin
    declare inq text;
    SET inq_mccd = IFNULL(inq_mccd,"");
    SET inq_prod = IFNULL(inq_prod,"");
    SET inq_item = IFNULL(inq_item,"");
    select concat('
        select distinct ',inq_type,' from condition_history
        where 1=1
        and (case when ? = "" then 1 else MCCODE like concat("%",?,"%") end)
        and (case when ? = "" then 1 else PRODSTD like concat("%",?,"%") end)
        and (case when ? = "" then 1 else ITEMCODE like concat("%",?,"%") end)
    ') into inq;
    
    prepare stmt from inq;
    execute stmt using inq_mccd, inq_mccd, inq_prod, inq_prod, inq_item, inq_item;
    
end//
delimiter ;
```

-- singlie input works well

```
call listview("ITEMCODE", "XMC029" , Null, Null);
```

-- multi input not works, i want both single input and multi input lke this

```
call listview("ITEMCODE", "XMC029,XMC030", "X-R-080", Null);
```

call listview("ITEMCODE", "XMC029,XMC030", "X-R-080", Null);

Comment: Is inq_mccd the only input parameter which can be multi-value?

Comment: nope, every valuse can be single, mulit_value!!! I already solveed this problem,,, thx :)